How to store lists for arbitrary keys in Zustand?
My react app needs to store chat messages for different chat rooms. What chat rooms exist is of course dynamic. Currently in Zustand I store these in an attribute defined like this: messagesByChannel: Record<string, ChatMessageData[]>; and expose them like this:
getMessages: (channelId) => {
        return get().messagesByChannel[channelId] || [];
},

This seems to give me a infinite loop Error when I use it in my component like this:
const chatMessages = useChatStore((state) => state.getMessages(channel?.id));

At one point I changed my component to instead bind to getMessages rather than invoking it and then called it when needed. This resulted in no re-renders.
I did consider adding the channelIds as keys to the Zustand state directly at the top level, but that feels potentially messy and would clash with TypeScript's expectation for proper typing.
What's the common approach for this type of issue? It seems like this would be a common problem with a common solution, no?
Thank you for all input, it's my 1st day of Zustand !

Does it give you an infinite loop on empty message chats only? Or ones that may return 'null' or 'undefined' from get().messagesByChannel[channelId]?

Wondering if this could be due to || [] statement, because ([] !== []) as these are two different references, that may cause infinite re-renders

@pavlo-sobchuk's comments helped me identify the issue and solve it by a simple application of useShallow() like this: const chatMessages = useChatStore(useShallow((state) => state.getMessages(channel?.id)));
